# Apache low idle workers but not at max requests

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have default max workers for apache, connection re-use disabled very low memory and CPU utilization and load, low IO latency but my idle workers seems to be very low. Sometimes approaching or at 0 and not really steady at all, it spikes high and low a ton. I serve a basic php login page with very few elements.

It seems to me that the math should be

```
idle workers=256-(requests currently being processed)
```

but that's not the case. 
Apache scoreboard shows (if I catch it at the right time):

```
121 requests currently being processed, 10 idle workers

CRCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCRCCCRCCCRCCCCRCWCWCCCCCCCCCCCRCCRCCCCRRCRC
CCCCCCCRCCCCCCRCCCCCCCCCCCCCCWR_CCCC_CCCCCCCRCCCRCCCCCCCCC.CCC..
RCCC.C.C.....R.................C.......C........................
C........C...C..........CR....C.C.....R...........C....C.R..C.R.
```

It would also seem to me that a "." indicates an idle worker. What am I missing? I want to make sure there aren't microbursts of 0 idle workers affecting my service.

Comment: You might get a better response for something like this over at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (or one of the other network sites) since this doesn't really seem to be a coding/programming question.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but the vast majority of apache questions are asked and answered here on SO.

Comment: Looking in the `apache` tag, I see one single answered question in the last 24 hours.  So I'm not sure I'd agree with that.  It was just a suggestion though.  If your experience is to the contrary, you're more than welcome to leave it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-performance-tuning-mpm-directives/#prefork

> MinSpareServers
>
> This directive defines a minimum number of spare children the Apache
> parent process can maintain in its memory. An additional server is a
> preforked idle Apache child that is ready to respond to a new incoming
> request. Having idle children waiting for new requests is essential
> for providing the fastest server response times. When the total idle
> children on the server drop below this value, a new child is preforked
> at the rate of one per second until this directive is satisfied. The
> “one per second” rule is in place to prevent surges of the creation
> process that overload the server, however, this failsafe comes at a
> cost. The one per second spawn rate is particularly slow when it comes
> to handling page requests. So it’s highly beneficial to make sure
> enough children are preforked and ready to handle incoming requests.

Comment: Since Apache 1.3, the "one per second" rule was relaxed and was replaced with an exponential spawning: 1 per second, then 2 per second, then 4 per second, with a max rate of 32 per second.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html